# Check if the product exists in the shopping cart - Cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Friends, I appreciate if anyone can analyze.

I add items to the shopping cart according to the code below.

```
    public function add()
    {

        $order = $this->Orders->newEntity();

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

            $order = $this->Orders->patchEntity($order, $this->request->getData());
            $order->product = $this->Orders->Products->get($order->product_id, ['contain' => ['Users']]);
            $session = $this->request->getSession();
            $cart = $session->read('cart');
            $cart[] = $order;

            if (isset($cart[$order->product_id])) {
           //product is already in the cart
            } else {
            $cart[$order->product_id] = $order;
            }

           $product = $this->Orders->Products->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
           $users = $this->Products->Users->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
           $this->set(compact('order', 'products', 'users'));
       }
   }
```

I can add products to the normal cart, but I can't prevent the same product from being added multiple times. It needs to be only once.

Thanks for any comment!

Comment: can you post the output of `print_r($cart);` and `print_r($session->read())`

Comment: The order information is just: 'product_id' => (int) 31, 'quantity' => (int) 1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this

```
if (isset($cart[$order->product_id])) {
    //product is already in the cart
} else {
    $cart[$order->product_id] = $order;
}
```

It should be something like this (as I don't have your full code)

```
 // counter is to check if the product_id already exists
       
$counter = 0;
foreach($cart as $cartOne){
    
    if($cartOne['product_id'] == $order->product_id){
        $cartOne['quantity'] += 1;
        $counter++;
    break;
    } 
}

if($counter == 0){
    $cart[$order->product_id] = $order;
}
$counter = 0;
```

**Full Code Here:**

```
public function add(){

    $order = $this->Orders->newEntity();

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $order = $this->Orders->patchEntity($order, $this->request->getData());
        $order->product = $this->Orders->Products->get($order->product_id, ['contain' => ['Users']]);
        $session = $this->request->getSession();
        $cart = $session->read('cart');
        $cart[] = $order;

        // counter is to check if the product_id already exists
           
        $counter = 0;
        foreach($cart as $cartOne){
            
            if($cartOne['product_id'] == $order->product_id){
                $cartOne['quantity'] += 1;
                $counter++;
            break;
            } 
        }
        
        if($counter == 0){
            $cart[$order->product_id] = $order;
        }
        $counter = 0;

        $product = $this->Orders->Products->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $users = $this->Products->Users->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $this->set(compact('order', 'products', 'users'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But it gives error: "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: I have added the full code in my answer. Please check now

Comment: Now gave this error: Record not found in table "products" with primary key [NULL]

Comment: Error in this line `$order->product = $this->Orders->Products->get($order->product_id, ['contain' => ['Users']]);`. Check if `$order->product_id` is valid

Comment: It is valid, it had a typo. Now it indicates the error: Undefined property: OrdersController :: $Products in. In the line: $users = $ this->Products->Users-> find ('list', ['limit' => 200]); "Call to a member function find() on null"

Comment: again a typo. `$ this->Products->Users->`. Space between `$` and `this`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217344/discussion-between-chilarai-and-edrian-biagi).